# Measuring memory usage of distributed arrays

Tags: julia

I've been having trouble measuring the memory usage of distributed arrays and could not find a solution on [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/memory-size-of-distributedarray/8085).  Consider the following example.

```
addprocs(2)
@everywhere using DistributedArrays
m = [rand(100,100) for i in 1:1000]
d = distribute(m)
```

How much memory does the array d use? I tried the following code, but its not quite right.

```
memory =  sizeof(d)
for a in d
    memory += sizeof(a)
end
```

It does not agree with the total memory usage indicated by my system. Any help would be greatly appreciated.